# Как прикрепить объект со сцены в компонент к созданному префабу

Tags: c#, unity3d, prefabs

Мне нужно программно проинициализировать объектом но сцены переменную `GameStatusData` скрипта MouseClick для объектов, которые были созданы через Instantiate из префаба.
[image: Есть ли в юнити команда, которая может выполнить это действие?]
Подробнее о сути проблемы:

1. Я генерирую префабы при запуске игры
2. В них вложены спрайты
3. К спрайтам прикреплен скрипт, который должен определять была ли нажата мышь на какой-либо из спрайтов и отправлять экземпляр GameObject в другой скрипт.

Из-за того, что скрипт, куда я должен отправлять GameObject, прикреплен к объекту со сцены игра на этом встает.

Да, я могу сделать статик класс и передавать GameObject туда, тогда проблемы не будет, но мне хочется узнать, как ещё можно решить этот вопрос.

Comment: Советую переформулировать вопрос: добавить рестейт вопроса после ее описания проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В скрипт, создающий префабы, добавить `[SerializeField] private` переменную типа `GameStatusData` и проинициализировать ее нужным значением.
2. После создания префаба добавлять к нему компонент `MouseClick` с помощью [AddComponent()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html).
3. Установить переменную `GameStatusData` компонента `MouseClick` только что созданного объекта значением переменной из пункта 1.

Примерный полукод:

```
class PrefabsSpawner {
    [SerializeField] private GameStatusData data; // Установить из инспектора
    [SerializeField] private GameObject Prefab;
    void SpawnPrefab () {
        GameObject newObj = Instantiate(Prefab, ...);
        newObj.AddComponent<MouseClick>();
        newObj.GetComponent<MouseClick>().GameStatusData = data;
    }
}
```

Еще, конечно, есть [FindObjectOfType()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html), но легче будет указать из инспектора. Да и вообще FindObjectOfType - так себе практика.

Comment: Спасибо Максим, Именно это я и искал, вы верно поняли, что я хотел